# How to use python to click the “load more” to extract links of names

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, pagination

I want to get links of names from all the pages by clicking load more and needs help with pagination

I've got the logic to print links for names but needs help with pagination

```
for pos in positions:
    url = "https://247sports.com/Season/2021-Football/CompositeRecruitRankings/?InstitutionGroup=HighSchool"
    two = requests.get("https://247sports.com/Season/2021-Football/CompositeRecruitRankings/?InstitutionGroup=HighSchool" + pos,headers=HEADERS)
    bsObj = BeautifulSoup(two.content , 'lxml')
    main_content = urljoin(url,bsObj.select(".data-js")[1]['href'])  ## ['href']InstitutionGroup" extracting the link leading to the page containing everything available here
    response = requests.get(main_content)
    obj = BeautifulSoup(response.content , 'lxml')
    names = obj.findAll("div",{"class" : "recruit"})

for player_name in names:
    player_name.find('a',{'class' : ' rankings-page__name-link'})    
    for all_players in player_name.find_all('a', href=True):

        player_urls = site + all_players.get('href')
       # print(player_urls)
```

I expect output : https://247sports.com/Player/Jack-Sawyer-46049925/
(links of all player names)

Answer (score 0):

Can just iterate through the parameters in the requests. Since you can just continue to iterate forever, I had it check for when players started to repeat (essentially when the next iteration doesn't add new players). Seem to stop after 21 pages which gives 960 players.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://247sports.com/Season/2021-Football/CompositeRecruitRankings/'

headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.90 Safari/537.36'}

player_links = []
prior_count = 0
for page in range(1,101):
    #print ('Page: %s' %page)
    payload = {
    'ViewPath': '~/Views/SkyNet/PlayerSportRanking/_SimpleSetForSeason.ascx',
    'InstitutionGroup': 'HighSchool',
    'Page': '%s' %page}

    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=payload)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')


    recruits = soup.find_all('div',{'class':'recruit'})
    for recruit in recruits:
        print ('https://247sports.com' + recruit.find('a')['href'])
        player_links.append('https://247sports.com' + recruit.find('a')['href'])

    current_count = len(list(set(player_links)))
    if prior_count == current_count:
        print ('No more players')
        break
    else:
        prior_count = current_count
```

**Output:**

```
print (player_links)
['https://247sports.com/Player/Korey-Foreman-46056100', 'https://247sports.com/Player/Jack-Sawyer-46049925', 'https://247sports.com/Player/Tommy-Brockermeyer-46040211', 'https://247sports.com/Player/James-Williams-46049981', 'https://247sports.com/Player/Payton-Page-46055295', 'https://247sports.com/Player/Camar-Wheaton-46050152', 'https://247sports.com/Player/Brock-Vandagriff-46050870', 'https://247sports.com/Player/JT-Tuimoloau-46048440', 'https://247sports.com/Player/Emeka-Egbuka-46048438', 'https://247sports.com/Player/Tony-Grimes-46048912', 'https://247sports.com/Player/Sam-Huard-46048437', 'https://247sports.com/Player/Amarius-Mims-46079928', 'https://247sports.com/Player/Savion-Byrd-46078964', 'https://247sports.com/Player/Jake-Garcia-46053996', 'https://247sports.com/Player/Agiye-Hall-46055274', 'https://247sports.com/Player/Caleb-Williams-46040610', 'https://247sports.com/Player/JJ-McCarthy-46042742', 'https://247sports.com/Player/Dylan-Brooks-46079585', 'https://247sports.com/Player/Nolan-Rucci-46058902', 'https://247sports.com/Player/GaQuincy-McKinstry-46052990', 'https://247sports.com/Player/Will-Shipley-46056925', 'https://247sports.com/Player/Maason-Smith-46057128', 'https://247sports.com/Player/Isaiah-Johnson-46050757', 'https://247sports.com/Player/Landon-Jackson-46049327', 'https://247sports.com/Player/Tunmise-Adeleye-46050288', 'https://247sports.com/Player/Terrence-Lewis-46058521', 'https://247sports.com/Player/Lee-Hunter-46058922', 'https://247sports.com/Player/Raesjon-Davis-46056065', 'https://247sports.com/Player/Kyle-McCord-46047962', 'https://247sports.com/Player/Beaux-Collins-46049126', 'https://247sports.com/Player/Landon-Tengwall-46048781', 'https://247sports.com/Player/Smael-Mondon-46058273', 'https://247sports.com/Player/Derrick-Davis-Jr-46049676', 'https://247sports.com/Player/Troy-Franklin-46048840', 'https://247sports.com/Player/Tywone-Malone-46081337', 'https://247sports.com/Player/Micah-Morris-46051663', 'https://247sports.com/Player/Donte-Thornton-46056489', 'https://247sports.com/Player/Bryce-Langston-46050326', 'https://247sports.com/Player/Damon-Payne-46041148', 'https://247sports.com/Player/Rocco-Spindler-46049869', 'https://247sports.com/Player/David-Daniel-46076804', 'https://247sports.com/Player/Branden-Jennings-46049721', 'https://247sports.com/Player/JaTavion-Sanders-46058800', 'https://247sports.com/Player/Chris-Hilton-46055801', 'https://247sports.com/Player/Jason-Marshall-46051367', ... ]
```

Comment: it's giving output as:Page: 1
Page: 2
Page: 3
Page: 4
Page: 5
Page: 6
Page: 7
Page: 8
Page: 9
Page: 10    I want the links of players name to be printed

Comment: Ya. It's not storing that, it's just so I know it's running. the links are in the list. `print (player_links)` I'll edit the code so it prints the list

Comment: @agnivy, give it run again. I added it to print it out

Comment: thank you so much for the solution you've provided it helped me a lot